# How to Parse KML file and check point inside kml polygon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, kml

I have this code in Javascript and it is working fine..Now i want to do same thing in rails.I Want to check whether given latitude and longitude in given polygon or not.I have check the ruby-kml,georuby and porth-kml gems but do not get any thing relavant.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      var geoXml = null;
      var flag = 0;
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),myOptions);
      var address = "<%= current_user.present? ? current_user.full_address : '' %>"
      var myOptions = {
        zoom: 12,
        mapTypeControl: true,
        mapTypeControlOptions:{style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},
        navigationControl: true,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      }
      infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({size: new google.maps.Size(150,50)}); 
      $(document).ready(function() {    
        load_map();
      });

      function load_map() {
        geoXml = new geoXML3.parser({map: map, singleInfoWindow: true, infoWindow: infowindow});
        geoXml.parse("<%= @resturant.district.kml_url %>");
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();  
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var point = results[0].geometry.location;
            for (var i=0; i<geoXml.docs[0].gpolygons.length; i++) {
              if (geoXml.docs[0].gpolygons[i].Contains(point)) {
                flag = 1;
                i = 999;           
              }
            }
            if (flag!=1){
              $(".link_modal").attr("data-target","#map_modal");}
            }
          }else {
            return false;
          }
        });
      }
    </script>
```

Comment: Since KML is XML based and you haven't found a gem with an adequate parser you can always write your own using Nokogiri, maybe?

Comment: Border_patrol https://github.com/square/border_patrol Works for me.